# How to get the facebook fan page private messages through fql or graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messages

I have tried [Page Messages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#conversations)

with the all the required permission i.e read_mailbox, read_page_mailboxes, etc (all the extended permission)

at length I get tried as

```
https://graph.facebook.com/456330641095467/conversations?access_token=BAAGgcfpJgfUBAHdKaE6KxMWo4rU6VU7psX7Ip4cLbG1yIvX80fkkTXm3ZApdYHmcISmqfnns1gPYZAHXWD2cXX7nMBcj4AK31uptfqJUjNAGXan1ftOK4Tw3sY1WsZD
```

but i get response as

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#210) Subject must be a page.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 210
   }
}
```

I am unable to find out the issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the access_token of page and you are done

yours output would be like this

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "t_id.615971188431960",
         "snippet": "ok fine reply on test 5:15",
         "updated_time": "2013-04-16T12:15:12+0000",
         "message_count": 8,
         "tags": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "inbox"
               },
               {
                  "name": "read"
               },
               {
                  "name": "seen"
               },
               {
                  "name": "sent"
               },
               {
                  "name": "source:web"
               }
            ]
         },
         "participants": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Pragati Singh",
                  "email": "100000441901858\u0040facebook.com",
                  "id": "100000441901858"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Devdemo",
                  "email": "456330641095467\u0040facebook.com",
                  "id": "456330641095467"
               }
            ]
         },
         "senders": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Devdemo",
                  "email": "456330641095467\u0040facebook.com",
                  "id": "456330641095467"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Pragati Singh",
                  "email": "100000441901858\u0040facebook.com",
                  "id": "100000441901858"
               }
            ]
         },
```